# Access cookie information in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there anyway to access the data associated with a cookie such as path, flags, and expiration date from javascript? All I've been able to find for cookie access is `document.cookie`, which only provides a list of name value pairs. Why is the interface for cookie access so limited?

Comment: The name value pairs should be the data you are looking for..

Comment: What about all the other information I listed? Of which path is the most critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is none, in terms of safe, cross-browser support.
Reasoning comes down to security.

The goal of cookies was to allow for communication back and forth from the browser to the server.
If you could allow *any* front-end script to manually edit the domain / path / expiration of a cookie, just for knowing its name, it would lead to a lot of potential security-holes, if not for spoofing access, then at least for invisibly tracking people.

That's not to say that cookies are inherently safe, or even particularly safe at all.
I mean to say that by allowing any and all JS to edit any and all cookie data sent to the server (moreso than just CRUD), any pretence of security would disappear in a heartbeat.

Comment: Actually, you can edit the path and expiration of cookies. You just can't read them for some reason. Ironically, the inability to read the paths of cookies leads to a potential security hole. In fact, javascript can "edit any and all cookie data sent to the server" (even http only cookies thanks to cookie jar overflow).

Comment: It's not actually editing a path, but rather making a second cookie which belongs to a second path. So you can have one site-level cookie with a specific name, and then one folder-level cookie of the same name, with the closest ancestor being the displayed cookie on the given page.  You can, of course, still edit the value, and yes, the expiry - I'm not sure why I mentioned that one, seeing as its the only way to mark a cookie for deletion (still lives until the browser-session ends). The domain and path are non-editable once set. You can set a value overtop, or make an overriding cookie...

Comment: @Antimony ...of a different subdomain/path, but you can't modify the original cookie's path/domain once set (without expiring it, and remaking a new one).

Comment: Which is something you can do. So you have the situation where you can write arbitrary cookies and you can read limited information about cookies, but not all of it. I have no idea why anyone would think a design like this is a good idea, and it certainly doesn't promote security.

Comment: @Antimony I think it's because it was intended to be a stopgap solution, meant for basic state-sharing, across largely-static pages (given that HTML was never intended to do what we've made it do, now) and a "working" spec which has barely been touched since some time in '95 /Netscape Mosaic/IE2...